# what is the meaning of this error using ktrain with preprocessing train function using python with deep learning

Tags: python, deep-learning, ktrain

i am trying to use deep learning  model in order to create sentiment analysis project.
For this i am using the **ktrain package** but the problem is in the `preprocess_train()`

The above function takes as parameters `def preprocess_train(texts, y=None, mode='train', verbose=1)`

```
Args:
    texts (list of strings): text of documents
    y: labels
    mode (str):  If 'train' and prepare_for_learner=False,
                 a tf.Dataset will be returned with repeat enabled
                 for training with fit_generator
    verbose(bool): verbosity
Returns:
  TransformerDataset if self.use_with_learner = True else tf.Dataset
```

based on the ktrain user guide i did the follow:

## code:

```
import ktrain
from ktrain import text
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score,classification_report,confusion_matrix
from sklearn import metrics

MODEL_NAME = 'aubmindlab/bert-base-arabertv01'
t = text.Transformer(MODEL_NAME, maxlen=128)
trn = t.preprocess_train(X_train_smote.Tweet.values, y_train_smote)
val = t.preprocess_test(X_test.Tweet.values, y_test)
model = t.get_classifier()
learner = ktrain.get_learner(model, train_data=trn, val_data=val, batch_size=32)
```

where:

`X_train_smote.Tweet.values` --> array([1830,  471, 1100, ..., 1308,  930,  868])

`type(X_train_smote.Tweet.values)` --> numpy ndarray

`y_train_smote` --> array(['NEGATIVE', 'NEGATIVE', 'POSITIVE', ..., 'POSITIVE', 'POSITIVE',
'POSITIVE'], dtype=object)
`type(y_train_smote)` --> numpy ndarray

The system crash and display the below error :

```
preprocessing train...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-81-78dde2289830> in <module>()
      6 MODEL_NAME = 'aubmindlab/bert-base-arabertv01'# using the Arabert
      7 t = text.Transformer(MODEL_NAME, maxlen=128)
----> 8 trn = t.preprocess_train(X_train_smote.Tweet.values, y_train_smote)
      9 val = t.preprocess_test(X_test.Tweet.values, y_test)
     10 model = t.get_classifier()

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ktrain/text/preprocessor.py in detect_text_format(texts)
    231         is_pair = _is_sentence_pair(peek)
    232         if not is_pair and not isinstance(peek, str):
--> 233             raise ValueError(err_msg)
    234     return is_array, is_pair
    235 

ValueError: invalid text format: texts should be list of strings or list of sentence pairs in form of tuples (str, str)
```

Comment: it doesn't work..... your t.preprocess_train expects string as input.

Comment: so how to deal with this problem if i need to balance the dataset using SMOTE  than apply a deep learning model using ktrain package

Comment: Then you have to go with the feature based approach, that considers your vectors as input. Or you have to use alternate data augmentation technique to increase the number of text samples.